# Android: Slow UI rendering with simultaneous built-in and custom animations

Tags: android, animation, handler, ondraw

I need suggestions on using built-in and custom animations simultaneously.

My app have a screen with following animated views-

1. A view with rotate animation.
2. A view with AnimationDrawable and also a translate animation on it.
3. A custom view which simulate an animation by repeated onDraw() calls through a handler.

Animation 1 and 2 run simultaneously without any problem.

Animation of custom view alone also run smoothly.

But when I run all 3 simultaneously, they slow down each other.

It looks like they are running turn by turn,

when 1 and 2 run, 3 pauses for a while.

when 3 runs, 1 and 2 pause for a while.

Comment: post the code that cause your custom view to redraw